# MVC3: Jquery to click an Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

i got something to ask

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("menu", "itemList", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "divItemList" })
```

so i what i need is, everytime i click on that actionlink, it will trigger to click this another actionlink

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("item", "content", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "divContent" })
```

anyone can show me a jquery to do that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of, of the top of my head.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")',
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data)
    {
        $("#divContent").html(data);
    },
});
```